# Swift: How to install SwiftyJson using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swifty-json

I'm trying to install cocoapods here: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON but when I `import SwiftyJSON` in my view file, it says `No such module 'SwiftyJSON'`

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target 'SherpaNewYork' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end
```

After adding that I ran `pod install` succesfully:

```
[~/Documents/ios/Sherpa]$ pod install                                                                                                                                              ✭ git:master ruby:2.2.2
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `SwiftyJSON` from `https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git`
Downloading dependencies
Using GoogleMaps (1.10.4)
Installing SwiftyJSON (2.3.0)
[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pod being used is: SwiftyJSON
[~/Documents/ios/Sherpa]$ pod install                                                                                                                                              ✭ git:master ruby:2.2.2
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `SwiftyJSON` from `https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git`
Downloading dependencies
Using GoogleMaps (1.10.4)
Installing SwiftyJSON (2.3.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.
```

When I don't import it it gives me errors:

```
let jsonResponse: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = [
  ["id": "1",
    "name": "Crumbs Bakery",
    "icon_image": "food_icon_small",
    "latitude": 40.714,
    "longitude": -74.000
  ],
  ["id": "2",
    "name": "Shake Shack",
    "icon_image": "food_icon_small",
    "latitude": 40.715,
    "longitude": -74.001
  ]
]

let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonResponse, options: nil, error: nil

JSON(data) // Use of unresolved identifier 'JSON'
```

I even closed my Xcode and opened up "AppName.xcworkspace" but nothing works. Am I missing a step? I'm using pod v. 0.39.0 and my deployment target is 8.0.

Comment: I had the same problem becouse of did not use it in test target in progect, try to add this framework to test target

Comment: what's test target? you mean putting it in Linked Frameworks and Libraries?

Comment: I mean this http://imagehost.spark-media.ru/i4/453DE3BF-F5FA-DE51-0D6B-15EC8EBBB3C3.png in files where you use swiftyJSON if you have tests at your project

Comment: Are you using the right version of swifty json with the right version of swift?

Comment: yeh that was it @bolnad . i needed to upgrade xcode to 7

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: Misread your question. If you install it using Cocoapods, you still need to `import SwiftyJSON`.

Try `Product -> Clean` then `Product -> Build`. That may solves the problem.

---

You don't need to import it. Just use it. You only need `import` for a separated *module*: [Swift Access Controll](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html), not for *source file*.

Comment: but when I use `JSON` in my code it says `Use of unresolved identifier 'JSON'`

Comment: yes sorry I misread you question, please read my edited answer.

Comment: ok so after doing that i get like 27 issues from SwiftyJSON... which is both good and bad news. I can't build anymore because of these errors

Comment: I've just made a test project with SwiftyJSON Cocoapods and it builds and runs without any issues. What are your issues? Try clean project again.

Comment: i made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321464/swiftjson-cocoapods-pod-causes-a-lot-of-errors