# SwiftJSON + Cocoapods: SwiftJSON causes a lot of errors

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to install SwiftJSON, but after I install it using `pod install`, my project has a bunch of errors:

[image]

I'm using Xcode 6.4, my deployment target is 8.0 and my pod version is 0.39.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention about Xcode version in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321138/swift-how-to-install-swiftyjson-using-cocoapods/33321204).

SwiftyJSON [requires Xcode 7](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#requirements), because Xcode 6.4 can compile only Swift 1.2 and prior, SwiftyJSON is written on Swift 2.0.

Comment: Yes really. And you will need Xcode 7 anyway if you want to support iOS 9. Please mark this as accepted answer if it is... accepted :)